Use the value selected in a combobox in a variable to search a record
Im using a form "Abgabe_Unterlagen" to display from or enter records to a table "Abgabe_Unterlagen"
I got stuck by trying to use the value selected in a combobox "MandantenSuche"
Private Sub MandantenSuche_AfterUpdate()
   ' Den mit dem Steuerelement übereinstimmenden Datensatz suchen.
     
     Me.Recordset.FindFirst "Mandant_Nummer_F = " & MandantenSuche
     If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
          MsgBox "Nichts gefunden. Bitte neu eingeben.", vbInformation
          DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
          DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
     Else
          If vbYes = MsgBox("Zusätzl. Akte für Mandant eingeben ?", vbYesNo) Then
            ' Neue Akte anlegen
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
            DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
            'MandantName = MandantenSuche.Value
            'Mandant_Name.Value = MandantName
          Else
            'Öffne die bestehende Mandantenakte ...
            DoCmd.GoToControl "Art_Unterlage"
          End If
     End If
End Sub

I'd like to use that Variable value in the "Else" part of the code to select the record from the table "Mandantenliste" to already put the customer name and customer number in the form which at this point displays a new empty record.
Can anybody help ?
v/r
Banyan


Thank you very much for the hint,. I've updated the code and edited it in the post, as I'm getting an error when referring to that variable

You can access the data of a combobox column like this:
MandantName=Mandantensuche.Column(1)

Use 0 to refer to the first column, 1 to refer to the second column, and so on. In the example above I expect the name in the second column. Change the column number if necessary.

Thank you very much for the hint,. I've updated the code and edited it in the post, as I'm getting an error when referring to that variable –

Can you share the source of your combobox "MandantenSuche"? maybe you refer to the wrong column.

Could it be that there is a typo in your code?
You go to control "Mandant_Name" (with underscore) but assign the name to "MandantName" (without underscore).
By the way: in VBA you don't have to go to the control to manipulate it.

OK, I added all relevant screenshots ...sorry for the confusion...
Do I have to define a variable after all ?

You don't have to create a variable.
The combobox "Mandant_Name" saves the selection in field "Mandant_Nummer_F". This should be the same number your combobox "MandantenSuche" delivers: "MandantenListe.Mandant_Nummer", see "Gebundene Spalte" in your search combobox. if this is correct then you can pre-fill Mandant_Name like this:
Mandant_Name=MandantSuche

Hi Zen, thank you for your patience...with
"Mandant_Name=MandantSuche"
I'm getting an error
"you need to enter a Value  in field Abgabe_Unterlagen.Mandant_Nummer_F"

Isn't Mandant_Nummer_F not the combobox right to label "Mandant_Name"? I thought that this combobox has the name "Mandant_Name". I cannot see all details, naming and settings in your form there fore a little bit more abstract: you have to assign the value from "MandantSuche" to the Control which contains the Mandant_Nummer. -> [Your_ControlName_with_Mandant_Nummer]=MandantSuche

Yes that is correct Zen (wish I could add another screenshot, but the site wont allow that)
There is a Combo named "Mandant_Suche" with the "Mandatensuche" as the content field.
this control also contains the code in "after update"

The value from that content field is used to find a matching name record in table "Abgabe_Unterlagen"....if not found a new record added and displays empty in the form.
Here would it be great to use the value in "Mandatensuche to prefill  Mandant_Name - "Mandant_Nummer_F"
and Mandant_Nummer - "Mandant_Nummer"
in the new record.

Hooraay..I found the error...
there was code in: on Enter:
Private Sub MandantenSuche_Enter()
Me.MandantenSuche = Me.Mandant_Nummer
'DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
End Sub
to which the program jumped to and for that ignored the code in the module ;-) :-)
thank yo anyhow for chiming in and leading me in the right direction...
